# Django forms error placeholder

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using Django's ModelForms. I have placeholders on my text inputs, and I want the placeholders to change on error (as to indicate the error inside the inputs, not outside). I haven't found a way to override templates from widgets. How can I accomplish that?

```
class BusinessForm(ModelForm):
    color = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Business.colors)
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=BusinessCategory.objects.all(),
        to_field_name='id',
        empty_label='Select Business category'
    )
    image = forms.ImageField(widget=ImageInput(), required=False)

  class Meta:
      model = Business
      fields = ['name', 'strapline', 'story', 'category', 'color',
              'address', 'secondary_address', 'city', 'county', 'postcode',
              'phone_number', 'email', 'website', 'image']
      widgets = {
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Business name * Required'}),
        'strapline': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Business strapline'}),
        'story': forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your business story'}),
        'address': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Address 1'}),
        'secondary_address': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Address 2'}),
        'city': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Town/City'}),
        'county': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Country'}),
        #'postcode': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Postcode*', 'ng-blur': 'validatePostCode()', 'ng-model': 'postcode'}),
        'postcode': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Postcode * Required'}),
        'phone_number': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Business phone number * Required'}),
        'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Business email * Required'}),
        'website': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter business website e.g. www.mybusiness.co.uk'}),
    }
      labels = {
        'name': 'Business Name',
        'strapline': 'Business Strapline',
        'story': 'Your Business Story',
        'category': 'Select Business category',
        'address': 'Address 1',
        'secondary_address': 'Address 2',
        'city': 'Town/City',
        'county': 'Country',
        'postcode': 'Postcode*',
        'phone_number': 'Business phone number*',
        'email': 'Business email*',
        'website': 'Business Website',

    }
```

Comment: Placeholders will only be shown when there is no data for a field. That means the only class of message that will be shown in a placeholder is a "missing" error. Are you aware of this?

Comment: Yes. I don't think that should be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do that.

Placeholders are displayed only if the input values are blank (empty). It might work for required inputs but not for inputs with values in. In this case the placeholders will disappear and you cannot warn users with the wrong inputs.

That's why most websites are displaying errors next / above / below the inputs fields.

So if you still tend to place errors into placeholders for the empty inputs, you will have to use Javascript (e.g. with jQuery library).

For example if a user leaves an input (blur effect) you will check if the input is required. If so and the input is empty you will place the error into the placeholder attribute.

Comment: Ended up doing this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may pass an `attrs` dict to a widget, and if you are using the regular form rendering, these will be rendered:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': _('This is a required value')
    })
```

If you wanted this to only be shown on an error, then you'd possibly be able to set this in the `clean_name` method, although it's not normally the sort of thing you'd see in a `clean_*` method.

Alternatively, you could do it in the template. Have a look at [Django Sniplates](https://sniplates.readthedocs.org) for a nicer way of building django templates.

Comment: The clean_something method is not called when the field is empty, so that is practically useless. I have the placeholders in already, I just want them to change on error. I also don't want to introduce any new packages, because the site is finished already and my clients just want to change the way validation works. I'm trying to make minimal changes to it, not re-do the whole registration process.

Comment: Whoa, easy tiger. You understand I'm trying to help right? And your question hardly suggested that this was a virtually complete site... Perhaps you could just make the change in `clean`? Or, failing that, do it directly in your view (`form_invalid` if you are in a CBV).

Comment: Okay but I'm not sure how would I change the placeholders in the clean method? I've added an example of my form in my original answer.